# Using template literals for dynamic expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eval

How can i using dynamic values for evaluating expressions? For instance, consider the below example,

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

What if **a and b are dynamic names?** means instead of a and b it can be anything like 'someValue' . how to do something like below? (name can be dynamic)

```
 var 'someValue' = 1;
 console.log(`*Fifteen is ${'someValue' + b}* and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

In a nutshell i want to evaluate an expression where the field names are dynamic. So i wont be able to define variables statically. How do i overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean by "field names"?

Comment: have you tried ` console.log(`*Fifteen is ${someValue}  ${b}* and not ${2 * a + b}.`);` ?

Comment: names = 'a' , 'b' can be anything.. i cant define someValue statically

Comment: If the "names"  "can be anything" how will you know what they are? How do you know when `someValue` is defined within the current scope?

Comment: i need to programatically find the value ..say i was able find a =10 .. but how will dynamically assign the value to expression without defining the value before the expression?

Comment: _"i need to programatically find the value"_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bracket` notation and `this` keyword which is a reference to the **window** object.

```js
window.name="Vicky";
window.test="test";
const message = (p0, p1) => `Hello, ${p0}. This is a ${p1}`;
console.log(message(window['name'],window['test']));
```

Comment: Im roughly looking something like this .. for expression eval.. let me try this

Comment: @Vicky, replace `this` with `window`.

Comment: and `window.name="Vicky"`, `window.test="test"`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai can u provide a sample updated snippet to the answer  ^

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) will suits your needs. But be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) with this function.

```js
function test() {
  var a = 'Hello World',
      b = 1,
      c = 2,
      myVarRefA = 'a',
      myVarRefB = 'b',
      myVarRefC = 'c';
  
  console.log(`${eval(myVarRefA)} ${eval(myVarRefB + ' + ' + myVarRefC)}`);
}

test();
```

Comment: This snippet works better :) I will try to make this code modular to suit my needs. I hope this works

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai no i just saw that let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary Object with variables as its attributes

```
let temp = Object.create(null);
temp["someVar"] =3;
temp["anotherVar"]=2;
console.log(temp["someVar"] + temp["anotherVar"]);
```

But you can also use the more elegant

```
let temp = Object.create(null);
temp.someVar =3;
temp.anotherVar=2;
console.log(temp.someVar+ temp.anotherVar);
```

Do be careful about your "this" bindings

Comment: using the window object will leak variables into the global scope

Answer (score 0):

If your field names are completely custom, you can get use of [`Object.keys(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). This method will let you loop through the properties in an object.

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

**Example** *(Just to show usage)*

```js
    const customObject = { name: 'Foo', age: 23, city: 'Bar City' };
    const getFormatedObject = (fieldsObject) => {
      const fields = {};
      Object.keys(fieldsObject).forEach((fieldName, index) => {
        fields[`f${index}`] = fieldsObject[fieldName];
      });
      return fields;
    }
    const formatedObject = getFormatedObject(customObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(formatedObject).length; i++) {
      console.log(formatedObject[`f${i}`]);
    }
```

If you know the number of fields on your object you can go with something like below.

```js
const customObject = { name: 'Foo', age: 23, city: 'Bar City' };
const keys = Object.keys(customObject);
console.log(`His ${keys[0]} is ${customObject[keys[0]]} and ${keys[1]} is ${customObject[keys[1]]} and ${keys[2]} is ${customObject[keys[2]]}`);
```